# Chakra UI not working even after correct installation

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I have followed the docs on Chakra UI installation in React.js. The component I'm working on works in a separate project but the moment I add it to the current project, it does not the styles. Instead displays plain html

index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { ChakraProvider, theme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Test from "./pages/Test";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme} />
        <Test />
    <ChakraProvider />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Test.js

```js
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import {
    IconButton,
    Avatar,
    Box,
    CloseButton,
    Flex,
    HStack,
    VStack,
    Icon,
    useColorModeValue,
    Link,
    Drawer,
    DrawerContent,
    Text,
    useDisclosure,
    BoxProps,
    FlexProps,
    Menu,
    MenuButton,
    MenuDivider,
    MenuItem,
    MenuList,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import {
    FiHome,
    FiTrendingUp,
    FiCompass,
    FiStar,
    FiSettings,
    FiMenu,
    FiBell,
    FiChevronDown,
} from 'react-icons/fi';
import { IconType } from 'react-icons';
import { ReactText } from 'react';
import Rideshare from './Rideshare'
....
rest of my  code
```

package.json

```json
.....

"dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.3.7",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.13.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.6",
    "framer-motion": "^6.5.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "query-string": "^6.13.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "reactstrap": "^9.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "remixicon": "^2.5.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
.....
```

I have tried reinstalling Chakra-UI using the command

```bash
npm i @chakra-ui/react @emotion/react @emotion/styled framer-motion
```

but this solution hasn't worked. My `package.json` shows that Chakra-UI is installed.

Answer (score 3):

I have gone and tried to check up on some [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny1Fa.png) on this. Looks like you need to place the Chakra Provider in the root of your project.

Another problem may be that [<React.StrictMode>](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) doesn't render any visible UI, so you may have to remove that

Comment: it is placed in the root `index.js` file. I don't know about strictmode though

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in index.js file..

Correct index.js to the following,

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { ChakraProvider, theme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Test from "./pages/Test";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
        <Test />
    </ChakraProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: note that answering questions about typos is discouraged

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).